# Time-Date and Event chart or Graph in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, google-visualization

I'm using highchart graphs to display time and event of specific person. But I don't understand which graph to use.
Following image is the example. I want to do the same.[image]

Comment: For something like this, charting seems like overkill, you could just have a series of div sections with a pop over that jQuery can hook into above some of them. `<div>date</div><div data-event="event 1">date</div>...`

Comment: @Totoro: Can you gimme any example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/kiwitotoro/oqz0n84h/) which only uses css and html. It is very limited but functions (fixed width tool tips etc). You could easily make it more flexible, it is just to show it is possible.

```
<div class="list">
    <div class="period">...</div>
    <div class="period">15/5
        <span class="tool-tip">info</span>
    </div>
    <div class="period">16/5/2015
        <span class="tool-tip">info 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="period">17/5
        <span class="tool-tip">fixed width</span>
    </div>
    <div class="period">18/5</div>
    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
</div>

.period{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    ...
}
.tool-tip{
    height:35px;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    ...
}
```

Main thing to be aware of is that each section is an inline box, then the tool tip is located relative to it.

Comment: Hey thanks for the example. I tried using simple HTML tags and bootstrap popover. Some grails tags and logic did a trick. Its working.

Comment: Glad it helped with your task.